# Cannot inject spring data JPA repository into EJB bean on WebSphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-data, websphere, weld

I try to integrate CDI spring-data-jpa in Java EE environment.

I created a very simple repository:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, String> {
}
```

I also added the CDI producer for the EntityManager:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Then I want to inject this repository to another CDI bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleService {

    private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    public SampleService() {
    }

    @Inject
    public SampleService(SampleRepository sampleRepository) {
        this.sampleRepository = sampleRepository;
    }

}
```

and also into EJB. For JBoss EAP 7.1 application server it works great - the repository is injected correctly for CDI bean or EJB and I can run queries on the database. However, for WebSphere, I am getting the following exception during startup and the application cannot start:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type SampleRepository with qualifiers
>   @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1
>   of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public
>   com.sample.ejb.SampleEJB(SampleRepository)   at
>   com.sample.ejb.SampleEJB.(SampleEJB.java:0)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:362)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:501)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)

Comment: Have you inserted @EnableJpaRepository annotation ?

Comment: I tried with and without annotation @EnableJpaRepository - the same result.

Comment: Where did you place the annotation? How do you know it was read.'

Comment: did you place it together with Configuration annotation ?

Comment: What is SampleEJB?

Comment: SampleEJB = EJB @Stateless

Comment: I had to update the comment - it does not work for CDI beans as well - I was injecting the wrong type

Comment: I found that there is a class JpaRepositoryExtension which should create and add the repository beans. The constructor on WAS is called 4 times. However, the method processAnnotatedType which observes ProcessAnnotatedType event is never called.